# How to set JAVA_HOME Cloudera quickstart for Kafka and Zookeeper

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka, cloudera, cloudera-manager, cloudera-quickstart-vm

I have added Kafka service to my Cloudera cluster and when i try to start it it fails with the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/kafka/common/utils/KafkaThread : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
```

Which i understand is due to different java version and Kafka requires 1.8 while cloudera Quickstart has built in 1.7.  I have installed 1.8 but my cloudera is still picking up the 1.7 version.
I have updated JAVA_HOME and path veriables
Also updated .profile and .bashrc files.

Java --version on my terminal shows following output.

```
[root@quickstart default]# java -version
java version "1.8.0_231"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_231-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.231-b11, mixed mode)
```

but when i try to start the Kafka from cloudera Manager it shows following error. Kindly help.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you can do.

Login to the terminal of your name node. Stop all the services

```
    service hadoop-hdfs-datanode stop
    service hadoop-hdfs-journalnode stop        
    service hadoop-hdfs-namenode stop        
    service hadoop-hdfs-secondarynamenode stop        
    service hadoop-httpfs stop        
    service hadoop-mapreduce-historyserver stop        
    service hadoop-yarn-nodemanager stop        
    service hadoop-yarn-proxyserver stop        
    service hadoop-yarn-resourcemanager stop        
    service hbase-master stop        
    service hbase-regionserver stop
    service hbase-rest stop
    service hbase-solr-indexer stop
    service hbase-thrift stop
    service hive-metastore stop
    service hive-server2 stop
    service impala-catalog stop
    service impala-server stop
    service impala-state-store stop
    service oozie stop
    service solr-server stop
    service spark-history-server stop
    service sqoop2-server stop
    service sqoop-metastore stop
    service zookeeper-server stop
```

Stop Server and Agent

```
    service cloudera-scm-agent stop
    service cloudera-scm-server stop
```

Then add following into `/etc/bashrc`

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/jdk1.8.0_231
export JRE_HOME=${JAVA_HOME}
export JDK_HOME=${JAVA_HOME}
export ANT_HOME=/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.9.2
export M2_HOME=/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.0.4
export PATH=/usr/local/firefox:/sbin:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$ANT_HOME/bin:$M2_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Then finally restart the services and and Cluster from Cloudera Manager.

Answer (score 0):

Both bashrc and profile are for only your user.

If you want the whole system to change, you'd edit /etc/profile